How do we resolve that a Power Automate Sharepoint "Create item" action has changes in the UI that aren't reflected in Code View?
Changes to target different columns in a Power Automate Sharepoint list "Create item" action aren't reflected in the Code View of the action.
Although undesirable in and of itself this can cause a related problem. When you put a flow in a solution then export/import the solution to a new environment (or do this via a Pipeline): the flow in the target environment doesn't get updated according to what you set in the flow in the source environment, through the UI.
Reproduce the UI update V Code View mismatach:

Create a Sharepoint List, MyListDev with columns:

CoolCountry. Type: Single line of text;
SubmissionTimestamp: Type = Date and time; Include Time = Yes
SubmissionDatetime: Type = Date and time; Include Time = Yes


Create FieldSettingMweFlow02 with Actions

"Manually trigger a flow"
Sharepoint "Create item"

Site address: your site
List name: MyListDev
Parameters > CoolCountry: MexicoDEV
Parameters > SubmissionDatetime: utcNow()


Save
Test; Manually; [Test] ... [Run flow]
Observe Data good in Sharepoint MyListDev


Edit FieldSettingMweFlow02

Edit Sharepoint "Create item"

Parameters > SubmissionDatetime: [Blank]
Parameters > SubmissionTimestamp: utcNow()


Save;
Test; Manually; [Test] ... [Run flow]
Observe Data good in Sharepoint MyListDev. We've successfully pointed to "SubmissionTimestamp" instead of "SubmissionDatetime"





FieldSettingMweFlow02. Go out of flow and back into edit (to ensure the UI is up to date). Observe

Through the UI "Create Item" parameters are as before

Parameters > SubmissionDatetime: [Blank]
Parameters > SubmissionTimestamp: utcNow()







[Code View] however contains code that purports to populate "SubmissionDateTime" and not "SubmissionTimestamp" (nor for that matter "SubmissionDatetime", lower case "t")

      {
      "type": "OpenApiConnection",
      "inputs": {
        "parameters": {
          "dataset": "https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/MST_EXA_ExampleSite",
          "table": "some-guid",
          "item/CoolCountry": "MexicoDEV",
          "item/SubmissionDateTime": "@{utcNow()}"
        },
        "host": {
          "apiId": "/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_sharepointonline",
          "connection": "shared_sharepointonline",
          "operationId": "PostItem"
        }
      },
      "runAfter": {}
      }



In a sharepoint list:

The "Technical name" of the column will be different from the name we see in the UI, if we rename the column. This can cause the grief above.
To view the "Technical Name" there are two methods:

(Easiest): In Sharepoint sort the column and view the column name in the url. "&sortField=TechnicalNameOfColumn"; Or
Cog > List settings > Click on Column name: See column name in the url as "&Field=TechnicalNameOfColumn"


To solve:

Avoid renaming a sharepoint list column if possible.
If renaming is necessary: Create a new column with desired name. To achieve this, this might involve:

copying data from old column to an intermediate column
deleting the old column
creating the new column
copying from the intermediate column
deleting the intermediate column.





